# Validation of mobile number field

Tags: java, regex, validation, lost-focus

I want to know what's wrong with this code?
I am taking my input in the textbox(A 10-digit mobile number).
My problem is that, this code all the time prints else statement even if my input is correct.

```
mobNo=textMobNo.getText();

textMobNo.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[789]\\d{9}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mobNo);

        if (matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    };
});
```

Comment: Can you give examples of valid and invalid phone numbers in your locale?

Comment: See i want valid phone no as 9923568156.
and 926 is invalid. Phone No should be a 10 digit number.
check out that regular expression. you will get some idea from that.

Comment: Then why the "not 7, 8, or 9" at the beginning?

Comment: I suspect that value of `mobNo` is not what you think it is. Try to debug your code to check it or just invoke `System.out.println("'"+mobNo+"'");` before `if (matcher.matches()){`.

Comment: @hexafraction `[^789]` would be "not 7,8,9" but `^[789]` means beginning of the string and then 7 or 8 or 9.

Comment: Thats what i want, ^[789] means start of line and then 7 or 8 or 9.
Regx is correct. But output is wrong. :( I will try debugging.

Comment: Do you have same problem if you hardcode `mobNo` to `"9923568156"`?

Comment: Its just printing '' for mobno

Comment: Yeah even after hardcoding problem persists. But this time its printing correct value for mobno. but final output is still invalid.

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me http://ideone.com/WzUAHg. You need to provide some basic example that could be used to reproduce your error.

Comment: Its working now. Silly mistake. mobNo=textMobNo.getText(); this should be placed inside the lostfocus. Sorry!! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obtaining text from your text field, THEN adding a focusListener.  At some later time, the focus listener is fired, which then uses the text you got from your field before the focus listener was active.  Yeah, that text is probably from before anything was typed in the field; that would explain it being an empty string.  Try getting the text IN the focus listener... (hint - the string you get from the text field is not continually updated as text is typed in the field...)